# Embedded flash media player is not starting automatically upon web page load

Tags: html, css, flash

My flash media player is not playing automatically when my webpage loads. I have changed the settings from 0 to 1 (which should auto start the file), but still does not start the song automatically. This occurs in IE, FF, and Chrome. Thanks for any help.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="200" height="20">
    <param name="movie" value="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=/NewAYSsite/music/Great_is_Thy_Faithfulness_Crystal_Lewis.mp3&amp;autoplay=0&amp;autoload=1&amp;showstop=1&amp;showvolume=1&amp;bgcolor1=ffa50b&amp;bgcolor2=d07600" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `autoload=1` and set `autoplay=1` so your code looks like this:

```
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="200" height="20">
    <param name="movie" value="http%3A//flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=/NewAYSsite/music/Great_is_Thy_Faithfulness_Crystal_Lewis.mp3&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showstop=1&amp;showvolume=1&amp;bgcolor1=ffa50b&amp;bgcolor2=d07600" />
     </object>
```

If you can't get the mp3 to load then add a full path including the `http://`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `autoload=1` and set `autoplay=1` (or set `0`) so your code looks like this:

```
<i><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="200" height="20">
    <param name="movie" value="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=/NewAYSsite/music/Great_is_Thy_Faithfulness_Crystal_Lewis.mp3&amp;autoplay=0&amp;autoload=0&amp;showstop=1&amp;showvolume=1&amp;bgcolor1=ffa50b&amp;bgcolor2=d07600" />
</object></i>
```